# Ubuntu 18 boot time is very high after upgrade from 16 LTS

Tags: boot, upgrade, 18.04

I am facing startup time problems in ubuntu 18 after upgrade from 16 LTS. Below is the output of `systemd-analyze blame`

```
 1min 9.470s plymouth-start.service
 1min 8.107s plymouth-read-write.service
     48.640s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     45.970s apt-daily.service
     16.562s dev-sda8.device
     13.815s systemd-journal-flush.service
     13.615s keyboard-setup.service
     13.369s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
     12.658s systemd-sysctl.service
      9.577s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      4.732s mysql.service
      3.813s NetworkManager.service
      3.429s udisks2.service
      3.242s networkd-dispatcher.service
      2.815s apparmor.service
      2.640s snapd.service
      2.493s ModemManager.service
      2.329s accounts-daemon.service
      2.125s grub-common.service
      1.966s systemd-random-seed.service
      1.734s dev-loop8.device
      1.656s gpu-manager.service
      1.524s thermald.service
      1.489s dev-loop9.device
      1.443s dev-loop10.device
      1.323s dev-loop2.device
      1.323s dev-loop1.device
      1.322s dev-loop0.device
      1.319s dev-loop4.device
      1.314s dev-loop5.device
      1.313s dev-loop7.device
      1.312s dev-loop6.device
      1.305s dev-loop3.device
      1.037s systemd-remount-fs.service
      1.032s fwupd.service
       982ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
```

Does anyone have idea about how it can be reduced ? or if there is some problem with my system, how it can be fixed ?

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of hardware are you running this on? CPU type/speed and RAM would be helpful.

Comment: You may want to check this out here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037457/slow-boot-with-ssd-and-lvm-on-new-install-of-18-04/1037962#1037962                                                    or here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029050/long-boot-times-on-18-04?rq=1