# Slow Boot Time UBUNTU 18.04

Tags: boot, partitioning, xubuntu, swap

Ever since I increased disk space on UBUNTU 18.04, the booting time has increased manifolds.I created new swap partition. As pointed out by other answers for similar question, I have Updated the UUID in /ext/fstab.

I ran `systemd-analyze time` on terminal and the output is as follows:

```
Startup finished in 5.395s (firmware) + 6.836s (loader) + 4.535s (kernel) + 52.819s (userspace) = 1min 9.588s
graphical.target reached after 49.244s in userspace
```

On running `systemd-analyze critical-chain`:

```
graphical.target @49.244s
└─multi-user.target @49.244s
  └─kerneloops.service @40.919s +26ms
    └─network-online.target @40.913s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @32.043s +8.869s
        └─NetworkManager.service @27.622s +4.420s
          └─dbus.service @27.316s
            └─basic.target @27.312s
              └─sockets.target @27.312s
                └─snapd.socket @27.249s +62ms
                  └─sysinit.target @27.249s
                    └─cryptsetup.target @26.626s
                      └─systemd-ask-password-wall.path @2.985s
```

That 52.819 sec is unusual. I have searched over internet many times but nothing seems to resolve this issue.

EDIT: Output of systemd-analyze blame | head -n 20

```
19.189s systemd-journal-flush.service   
17.967s plymouth-start.service
17.193s plymouth-quit-wait.service
13.703s dev-sdb7.device
11.145s plymouth-read-write.service
8.869s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
6.558s dev-loop23.device
6.530s dev-loop20.device
6.448s dev-loop16.device
6.398s dev-loop22.device
6.332s dev-loop15.device
6.223s dev-loop21.device
6.202s dev-loop24.device
6.194s snapd.service
6.117s dev-loop18.device
5.971s networkd-dispatcher.service
5.943s dev-loop14.device
5.880s dev-loop17.device
5.754s dev-loop19.device
5.414s dev-loop10.device
```

Comment: Can you please post the output of

    systemd-analyze blame | head -n 20

Comment: Try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139513/how-to-clear-journalctl

Comment: As @Logix wrote, try to clean journal. For me it looks like the your hard drive is slow (dev-sdb7.device), are you sure that fstab (UUID) is correct? Additional you use a lot of snaps, is this really neccessary?

Boot time also slow down because of plymouth, but I realy do not know the root cause. Maybe graphic card driver... Just searched a bit and found similar issues from other users. Just check https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029050/long-boot-times-on-18-04 for reference.

Comment: @Mr.Michael.Schulze that doesnt seems to work for me.

Comment: @Mr.Michael.Schulze Will reinstalling UBUNTU 18.04 solve the issue?

Comment: @Naman You can always try a new installation and update all packages, etc. My personal opinion at the moment regarding Ubuntu 18.04, if not necessary just use 16.04. This is more stable.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar times on an XPS 9950 with a not partitioned 500 GB SSD (all of the HDD is dedicated to one OS). Ubuntu 17.10, 18.04 and 18.10 with Legacy boot was around your times. Now I have elementary OS Juno on UEFI and times did not changed much, I accepted it as normal even if I was expecting blazing fast boots in the Linux world.

Comment: I had also a slow boot with Ubuntu 18.04, but in my case it was caused by the network manager. I was not able to find a good solution for my situation and decided to change back to 16.04. So now with od 16.04 my boot time is approx 25 seconds and with 18.04 it was approx 90 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Last week I installed Xubuntu 18.04 on an old laptop and faced a similiar issue.
For me the most working solution was to disable the plymouth in grub with

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` into

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noplymouth video=SVIDEO-1:d"
```

After saving the change you must update the grub with

```
sudo update-grub
```

and then restart the machine.

I tried different options to disable the plymouth, sometimes without anything in quotest (just `""`) or with `"quiet splash"` and also with `"noplymouth"` without the `"video=SVIDEO-1:d"` option. For me at least it was not working or I got additional delay time during booting by krms or similar.